# Removing the Type and namespaces from Serialized XML

Tags: c#, xmlserializer

I have something like this as for my code I am using:

```
FileStream logStream = new FileStream(@"C:\mytest\mytest.xml", FileMode.Open);
XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(myProvider.GetType());
xmlSerializer.Serialize(logStream, MyProvider);
```

This generates an `XML` like this:

```
<ProviderType xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" ....
```

But in `Fiddler` and seeing the XML in the SOAP I see this:

```
<Provider .......
```

So it is not Provider**Type** and it doesn't have those **namespaces**...

How should I improve my code to generate an XML like that?

```
public ProviderType Provider
{
    get
    {
        return this.providerField;
    }
    set
    {
        this.providerField = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: How did you come up with the type returned by `MyProvider.GetType()`? Clearly, it doesn't have the correct attributes on it to generate the XML that you require.

Comment: @JohnSaunders MyProvider is just an object of type Provider that I am serializing

Comment: Was the `Provider` type intended to be serialized as `<Provider>`? It doesn't look like it was. It looks like it was intended to be serialized as `<ProviderType>`. Can you show (some of) the `Provider` class?

Comment: If you're new to XML Serialization, then you may not know that decorations on the type control the format of the serialized XML. So I think that the `Provider` class must have something like `[XmlElement(Name="ProviderType")]public class Provider{}` on it.

Comment: @JohnSaunders Thanks, I added it to the bottom of my question.

Comment: `Provider` is not a type. It's a property. The type is `ProviderType`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want an instance of the `ProviderType` class to serialize as `<Provider>`, then you have to say so:

```
[XmlRoot(Name="Provider")]
public class ProviderType
{
}
```

The extra namespaces you saw do not matter to any conforming XML implementation. Get everything else to match your desired XML before deciding that namespaces are the problem.

Comment: Ok thanks, I was worried about the XML namespaces but looks like it is normal for them to be there.